# Can I create facebook custom graph API action with name "Like" for custom object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In facebook graph API can I create custom action with name "*Like*" for any custom object?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use predefined actions names.

Comment: but it is working for my demo application and also approved. but when i am configure that same for live application and going to approve it will give me change for "I'm trying to submit a custom action that is not allowed. Remove this action, please submit this action instead of the embedded version.".

Comment: and also when you edit action in that page facebook also give like as in example of Name : " Examples: like, plan, review "

Comment: If you select action type "Like", you will use predefined action "Like". You can't change 'Connected Object Types'